# Role based access in Angular JS Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an Angular JS Single Page Application with a Grails backend. I know, if I am using a GSP page, its easy to provide role based content using tags from the spring security plugin-

  
    ...

Is there anything like this provided out of the box in Angular?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: NO. You are talking business logic here. AngularJS will not code it for you.

Comment: What is the best way to implement it in ng? Spring also does not code it for me but it provides a tag library that makes my task easier.

Comment: Spring is server side , not just client side ,aunthentication/autorisation is a server-side domain problem, not a client side one. how would you resolve that problem if you were to create a pure html app? your templates can be generated by spring ,your javascript files too.